# Why do I got NaN (loss) values in training Wasserstein GAN with Gradient Penalty?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

Recently, I worked with GANs for generating fake accelerometer data for human activity (i.e., mHEALTH dataset).

I have tried to implement Improved Technique for Training GAN (i.e., Conditional WGAN GP) from [here](https://github.com/kongyanye/cwgan-gp/blob/master/cwgan_gp.py). I have made some modifications on the code according to my data. My goal is to generate fake **1D time-series from single accelerometer data** with size (100,1) from input noise vector with size of 100.

However, when I run the code (training process), I got "**Nan**" for both discriminator loss and generator loss.

Did anyone have same problem like this ?
Why this problem happen and how to solve this problem ?
Thanks for your help !

Here my complete source [code](https://gist.github.com/furanzone/0b8eb824b71d5be292debb8581068b46)

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected trainable weights, did you set `model.trainable` without calling `model.compile` after ?
0 [D loss: 8.756878] [G loss: -0.499155]
10 [D loss: 5.958789] [G loss: -0.488709]
20 [D loss: 4.041764] [G loss: -0.473811]
30 [D loss: 2.644764] [G loss: -0.463494]
40 [D loss: 2.244551] [G loss: -0.460721]
50 [D loss: nan] [G loss: nan]
60 [D loss: nan] [G loss: nan]
70 [D loss: nan] [G loss: nan]
80 [D loss: nan] [G loss: nan]
90 [D loss: nan] [G loss: nan]
```